# Convert enum to char

Tags: java, hibernate, char, hibernate-mapping, enumerated

I'm working on a Hibernate project, here is an extract of my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_JOB")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqJob", sequenceName = "SEQ_JOB", allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Job {

    @Convert(converter = HibernateBooleenVersCaractere.class)
    @Column(name = "STATUT_EXTRACTION")
    private boolean statutExtraction;
}
```

In my database STATUT_EXTRACTION is a CHAR type that's why I used a converter (HibernateBooleenVersCaractere implements AttributeConverter) and it worked perfectly.
The boolean statutExtraction was usefull until now because I had only two state (OK = true = 1 in DB, Error = false = 0 in DB). But now I would like to add a state. In order to do that I created a enum state and used enumerated type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_JOB")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqJob", sequenceName = "SEQ_JOB", allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Job {
    public enum Statut {
        ERROR, OK, LOAD
    }

    @Column(name = "STATUT_EXTRACTION")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Statut statutExtraction;
}
```

Here I got an error caused by EnumType different from STATUT_EXTRACTION type in database I guess.

I had a second idea: use a converter as I did for converting boolean to char:

```
public class HibernateEnumVersChar
        implements
        AttributeConverter<Statut, Character> {

    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(final Statut statut) {
        if (statut == Statut.OK) {
            return '1';
        } else if (statut == Statut.LOAD) {
            return '2';
        } else if (statut == Statut.ERROR) {
            return '0';
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Statut convertToEntityAttribute(final Character dbData) {
        if (dbData == '1') {
            return Statut.OK;
        } else if (dbData == '2') {
            return Statut.LOAD;
        } else if (dbData == '0') {
            return Statut.ERROR;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And changed my Job class to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_JOB")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqJob", sequenceName = "SEQ_JOB", allocationSize = 1)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Job {
    public enum Statut {
        ERROR, OK, LOAD
    }

    @Convert(converter = HibernateEnumVersChar.class)
    @Column(name = "STATUT_EXTRACTION")
    private Statut statutExtraction;
}
```

And here I have this error:

> Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter

Sadly I can't change the database type (char) because I have a lot of data.

Has some one an idea where can my error be (or why not a different way to do what I need to do !) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest here is to use the `@Enumerated` annotation with the attribute `EnumType.ORDINAL`, `ORDINAL` here will get you a number `0`, `1` or `2` giving the order the value was defined in the Enum.

So when you define:

```
public enum Statut {
    ERROR, OK, LOAD
}
```

So here we will have:

```
Statut.ERROR.ordinal()  ---> gives 0
Statut.OK.ordinal()  ---> gives 1
Statut.LOAD.ordinal()  ---> gives 2
```

**Conculsion:**

Change your column definition like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "STATUT_EXTRACTION")
private Statut statutExtraction;
```

**Note:**

The database column should be changed to `NUMBER(1,0)`, or you can convert it to a `Char` inside your Enum definition, please read [**Hibernate & Enum handling** article](http://javadata.blogspot.com/2011/07/hibernate-and-enum-handling.html) for further details.

Comment: Damn thank you, I feel stupid, I thought EnumType.ORDINAL was for Enum with integers.

Comment: but this will really works ? Don't we need a NUMBER in DB when using EnumType.ORDINAL ?

Comment: @C.Norris You are welcome, gload it helps. Yes I forgot that, you need to map it as a `NUMBER(1,0)` in your DB, or use a converter again to convert it to a CHAR.

Comment: Then I will have @Enumerated + @Convert(Number to char) ? Isn't it the same to use immediatly what I tried: @Convert(Statut to char ?)

Comment: @C.Norris Yes but the best would be to use `NUMBER`, it will be more performant in Reading/Writing operat1ions, but you can handle the conversion in your ENUM definition please check [**Hibernate & Enum handling**](http://javadata.blogspot.com/2011/07/hibernate-and-enum-handling.html).